# dist error 404 for assets in production

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-cli

After adding base href URL in index.html

```
<base href=".">
```

i am run production mode using `"ng build --prod"`

moved dist folder into xampp htdocs folder after getting 404 Error added error image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's looking for it in the wrong dir, but things from `testing/dist/assets` are loading fine, so that might be a hint.

Also it's still running in dev mode as indicated in the console.

Comment: how to change dev mode? wrong dir means how can i change ?

Comment: When you build an app with ```ng build --prod``` it is outputted in the ```/dist``` folder. If you run ```ng serve``` it will still serve the dev version, to serve prod version run ```ng serve -prod```. Also ```.``` means look in the current dir, try using ```/``` instead, to look in the root dir and then write out the path from there.

Comment: possible to run without nodeJs?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem because the route of image are wrong like that
<img **src="../../assets/person.svg"** style="height: 50px;width: 50px;" alt="Avatar" (click)="infoUser()">
when you build in production mode de file main.js and asset directory are in the same leven so de route most be change like that
<img **src="assets/person.svg"** style="height: 50px;width: 50px;" alt="Avatar" (click)="infoUser()">